# Função em JS e querySelector

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde galera, eu estava hoje brincando com js, segue minha linha de código:

***index.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="password" name="" id="senha1">
    <input type="password" name="" id="senha2">
    <button id="btn">verificar senha</button>
</body>
</html>
```

***script.js***

```js
function validarSenha(){
    if (senha1.value == "" || senha2.value == ""){
        alert('você esqueceu uma das senhas')
    } else if (senha1.value == senha2.value){
        alert('as senhas são iguais');
    } else {
        alert('as senhas são diferentes');
    }
}

btn.onclick = validarSenha;
```

sei que vcs de cara podem falar que estão faltandos as seguintes linhas:

`senha1 = document.querySelector(#senha1)`
`senha2 = document.querySelector(#senha2)`
`btn = document.querySelector(#btn)`,

Porém qnd abri o ***index.html*** a minha função `validarSenha` funcionou da forma esperada, e fiquei curioso, pois pra mim teria que dar como undefined essas variaveis correto ? ou não, agradeço desde já a compreensão com minha leiguice

Comment: Oi Raphael! A tua pergunta é boa, e comum. Dei uma resposta sobre isso noutra pergunta, dá uma olhada nessa que marquei como duplicada.

Comment: muito obrigado @Sergio dei uma bugada mais tu clareou kkkkk valeu